# Majority element in an array

Tags: java

```
public class rough{
 public static int arrMajority1(int A[]){
  int n = A.length;
  int c = 1;
  for(int i=0;i>A.length;i++){

    for(int j=i+1;j<A.length;j++)
     if (A[i]==A[j])
      c=c+1;
      if (c>(A.length/2)){
      return A[i];
      }
     }
     return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
     int A[] = new int [] {5,5,8,7,5};
    // int arrMajority1 = A[0];
     System.out.println(" " + arrMajority1(A));
    }
}
```

A majority element in an array A of size N is an element that appears more than N/2 times. For example (3,3,4,2,4,4,2,4,4) has a majority element (4), whereas the array (3,3,4,2,4,4,2,4) does not have majority element.

Comment: And your question is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asking what's wrong with this code, I believe the main problem is the condition in the outer `for` loop.  I think is should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
```

(note the `<` rather than `>`).

Another problem is that you probably need to reset the `c` counter before each iteration of the outer `for` loop (otherwise, it will not keep a count of the *current* element being examined).  So try moving the `int c = 1;` statement to the blank line above the inner `for` loop.